# Did Jesus forbid the disciples from worshiping him before the Resurrection?

Tags: life-of-jesus, gospel-of-matthew, worship, resurrection

An  occasion on which we see the disciples worshiping Jesus is described in Mtt 28:17 :

> Then the eleven disciples went away into Galilee, to the mountain which Jesus had appointed for them.   When they saw Him, they worshiped Him; but some doubted.

That happened after the Resurrection. Even though  Jesus had appeared to three of them in glory during the Transfiguration, they did not worship him, but only got frightened (Lk 9:28-36; Mk 9:2-8; Mtt 17:1-7 ).

Matthew goes on to say in 17:9

> As they were coming down the mountain, Jesus instructed them, “Don’t tell anyone what you have seen, until the Son of Man has been raised from the dead.”

Of course, we also see Jesus being worshiped after his miraculous walk over the waters , in Mtt 14:32-33 :

> And when they climbed into the boat, the wind died down.  Then those who were in the boat worshiped him, saying, “Truly you are the Son of God.”

One reason why the disciples did not worship Jesus in public before the Resurrection could be that it would appear blasphemous to an onlooker.  But the Gospels do not  mention whether the  disciples wanted to worship Jesus in public before the Resurrection and whether he prohibited them .

My question therefore is: Did Jesus forbid  the disciples from worshiping him in public before the Resurrection ? Inputs from any denomination are welcome .

Comment: I would suggest the question requires an adjustment of _focus_. We know that there is no scripture in the gospels that records any prohibition by Jesus of his disciples worshipping him. Just a glance at a concordance indicates that. But the question highlights an aspect of Jesus' ministry in that after his ascension he is named Lord and Christ and after his resurrection he is declared Son of God. I would suggest that a definite alteration of focus would be edifying. Up-voted in the hope of a good outcome.

Comment: Thanks, Nigel . But Mtt 3:7 is loud and clear when it comes to public declaration of  Jesus as the Son of God at his baptism :    And a voice from heaven said, “This is my Son, whom I love; with him I am well pleased.” And, did not Thomas address Jesus as Lord and God even before the Ascension (Jn 20:28 )  ?  In fact, I have posted this question on CSE for the reason that a question of similar content in Quora has attracted  a lot of  undesirable answers.  Please bear with me.

Comment: The voice from heaven is unidentified. But, after resurrection . . . .  _And declared to be the Son of God with power, according to the spirit of holiness, **by the resurrection from the dead:**_ Romans 1:4. // And . . .  _God hath made that same Jesus, **whom ye have crucified**, both Lord and Christ._ Acts 2:36.

Comment: Thanks; I stand corrected.

Comment: " But the Gospels do not mention whether the disciples wanted to worship Jesus in public before the Resurrection and whether he prohibited them ."  Isn't this the answer to your question?

Comment: @NigelJ I think if I heard an "unidentified" voice from heaven making a declaration, I would believe it, wouldn't you?

Comment: @Biblasia   I am drawing attention to the fact that the voice did not identify itself : it identified the beloved Son. I was not suggesting that one would be incredulous. The text I am emphasizing is Romans 1:4 and its implications.

Answer (score 4):

**Jesus accepted worship prior to His Resurrection.** As one of the proofs that Jesus is God (because *accepting worship* would otherwise be condoning idolatry), there are quite a few sites that make note of those instances wherein this is recorded. For example:

- [Does the Bible describe Jesus being worshiped?](https://www.gotquestions.org/Jesus-worshipped.html)
- [Was Jesus worshipped during His earthly ministry?](https://www.compellingtruth.org/Jesus-worshipped.html)
- [Jesus Accepts Worship, Therefore He is God](https://humblesmith.wordpress.com/2010/11/09/jesus-accepts-worship-therefore-he-is-god/)

Notable examples of Jesus "accepting" worship (prior to His Resurrection) include:

- The magi visiting Him as an infant. (Although one could argue whether Jesus had and ability to influence the magi at this point, hence the quotes around "accepted".)
- The triumphal entry ("hosanna" is a plea for salvation and an expression of adoration).
- Matthew 14:33.
- John 9:38.

This list is not exhaustive; refer to the linked articles for additional examples. As to whether he forbade the *disciples*, specifically, to worship Him, I am not aware of any prohibitions to that effect. However, given that He accepted worship on multiple occasions from those who may or may not qualify as "disciples", it would seem odd that He would forbid his closest followers from worshiping him for what might be called "reasons of image" while *not* making such a prohibition more broadly.

Answer (score 2):

Jesus clearly taught that we should worship the Father.

> <sup>21</sup> Jesus saith unto her, Woman, believe me, the hour
> cometh, when ye shall neither in this mountain, nor yet at Jerusalem,
> worship the Father. <sup>22</sup> Ye worship ye know not what: we know
> what we worship: for salvation is of the Jews. <sup>23</sup> But the
> hour cometh, and now is, when **the true worshippers shall worship the
> Father** in spirit and in truth: for the Father seeketh such to
> worship him. (John 4:21-23, KJV)

He taught that the Father was *both* his God and our God.

> Jesus saith unto her, Touch me not; for I am not yet ascended to my
> Father: but go to my brethren, and say unto them, I ascend unto my
> Father, and your Father; and to my God, and your God. (John 20:17,
> KJV)

Jesus called the Father "the only true God."

> <sup>1</sup> These words spake Jesus, and lifted up his eyes to
> heaven, and said, **Father,** the hour is come; glorify thy Son, that
> thy Son also may glorify thee: <sup>2</sup> As thou hast given him
> power over all flesh, that he should give eternal life to as many as
> thou hast given him. <sup>3</sup> And this is life eternal, that they
> might know **thee the only true God,** and Jesus Christ, whom thou
> hast sent. (John 17:1-3, KJV)

Yet the Bible teaches that God, who is the Father, was in Christ.

> To wit, that **God was in Christ**, reconciling the world unto
> himself, not imputing their trespasses unto them; and hath committed
> unto us the word of reconciliation. (2 Corinthians 5:19, KJV)
>
> Believest thou not that I am in the Father, and **the Father in me?** the
> words that I speak unto you I speak not of myself: but **the Father that
> dwelleth in me,** he doeth the works. (John 14:10, KJV)

Because God was in Christ, invisible and unseen by human eyes, Jesus accepted the homage of people, without rebuking them, as directed to the Father.  To Jesus, their act of worship demonstrated their faith in the Father, whose words and works were manifested in the life of Christ.

But the Bible teaches, further, that God the Father has authorized the worship of Jesus.

> <sup>5</sup> For unto which of the angels said he at any time, Thou
> art my Son, this day have I begotten thee? And again, I will be to him
> a Father, and he shall be to me a Son?  <sup>6</sup> And again, when
> he bringeth in the firstbegotten into the world, he saith, And **let
> all the angels of God worship him**.  (Hebrews 1:5-6, KJV)

It is therefore no sin to worship Jesus, for the Father accepts this.

And Jesus accepted it, both before and after his resurrection.

> And as they went to tell his disciples, behold, Jesus met them,
> saying, All hail. And they came and held him by the feet, and
> worshipped him. (Matthew 28:9, KJV)
>
> But when he saw Jesus afar off, he ran and worshipped him, (Mark 5:6,
> KJV)

### Conclusion

The Bible's teaching is that it is acceptable to worship Jesus, for the Father has authorized this, and Jesus never once opposed it, but accepted it even before his death.

Comment: Stated clearly like our Master did at the well.  +1

Comment: Good answer, Biblasia. Mr 5:6 however, refers to the man with unclean spirit. NRSVCE says: When he saw Jesus from a distance, he ran and bowed down before him;   and he shouted at the top of his voice, “What have you to do with me, Jesus, Son of the Most High God? I adjure you by God, do not torment me.” I seriously doubt if that could be called worship. Even if it was, the public would not accuse him of blasphemy, would they ?

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan In Biblical culture (and language), the act of prostrating oneself in the presence of another is an act of worship.  Translators can legitimately translate this as "worship" or they may choose to translate the actions themselves.  The Greek word "προσκυνέω" of Mark 5:6 means to "prostrate oneself in homage."  In the KJV, it is translated as "worship" all 60 times it occurs in the New Testament.

Answer (score -8):

**No Jesus does not reject worship.  However, Jesus is NEVER worshiped AS the 1 God, YHWH his Father, who he always speaks of.**

Jesus tells the woman at the well who to worship **AS GOD.**

John 4 KJV

> 21 Jesus saith unto her, Woman, believe me, the hour cometh, when ye shall neither in this mountain, nor yet at Jerusalem, ***worship the Father***.22 Ye worship ye know not what: we know what we worship: for salvation is of the Jews.23 But the hour cometh, and now is, when *the true worshippers* shall **worship the Father in spirit and in truth**: for **the Father** seeketh such to worship him.24 **God is a Spirit**: and they that worship **Him** must **worship Him in spirit and in truth.**

Instead of interpreting Jesus as receiving worship as the 1 God, **a much more *Rational* interpretation is  available for those with *ears to hear.*** I present it for you now:

We see the **worship of persons other then YHWH being permitted in scripture**.  Here are some examples.

Revelation 3:9 (KJV)

> Behold, I will make them of the synagogue of Satan, which say they are Jews, and are not, but do lie; behold, I will make them to come and ***worship*** before thy feet, and to know that I have loved thee.

Matthew 18:26 (KJV)

> The servant therefore fell down and ***worshiped*** him, saying, Lord, have patience with me, and I will pay thee all. 27  Then the lord of that servant was moved with compassion, and loosed him, and forgave him the debt.

1 Chronicles 29:20

> And David said to all the congregation, Now bless the Lord your God. And all the congregation blessed the Lord God of their fathers, and bowed down their heads, and ***worshipped*** the Lord, **and** the king.

Joseph was also worshiped by his brothers as the ruler over them and he was also given a dream from God that he would be also and again it is the same word used for worship of God as was used for his brothers bowing to him in worship.

The Revelation Throne room scene in chapters 4 and 5 illustrate my conclusion the *best*.

Rev4:8- 11

> <sup>**8**</sup> And the four beasts had each of them six wings about him; and they were full of eyes within: and they rest not day and night, saying, Holy, holy, holy, Lord God Almighty, which was, and is, and is to come.
>
> <sup>**9**</sup>
> And when those beasts give glory and honour and thanks to **him that sat on the throne**, who liveth for ever and ever,
>
> <sup>**10**</sup>
> The four and twenty elders fall down before him that sat on the throne, and worship him that liveth for ever and ever, and cast their crowns before the throne, saying,
>
> <sup>**11**</sup> Thou art worthy, O LORD, to receive glory and honour and power: for thou hast created all things, and for thy pleasure they are and were created.

In the next chapter, we read that the Lamb is in the midst of the throne with the elders.  He takes the scroll from the One being worshiped as the Creator of everything.

> <sup>**5:6**</sup>And I beheld, and, lo, in the midst of the throne and of the four beasts, and in the midst of the elders, stood a Lamb as it had been slain, having seven horns and seven eyes, which are the seven Spirits of God sent forth into all the earth.

> <sup>**7**</sup>And he came and took the book out of the right hand of him that sat upon the throne.

So we can objectively understand by this scene in scripture that the Lamb is **not** being worshiped as God, but is receiving praise for his victory and his worthiness to open the seals. The **only** begotten is the **only** one who can do this.

**ONLY worship our Father, YHWH, AS the One True God.**  John 17:3

Comment: If anyone disagrees enough to downvote... Here is your opportunity to explain fully why 
https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/93004/60347

Comment: RLPM, please read Jn 17 from the beginning:   "These words spake Jesus, and lifted up his eyes to heaven, and said, Father, the hour is come; glorify thy Son, that thy Son also may glorify thee  ".  Jesus addresses God as  Father, not as YHWH ! Flashback Jn 14:10 : 
 "Do you not believe that I am in the Father and the Father is in Me? The words I say to you, I do not speak on My own. Instead, it is the Father dwelling in Me, performing His works. "  Does that make sense ?

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it doesn't answer the question asked, but instead follows various tangents. The question doesn't ask whether Jesus rejected worship as YHVH, nor does it ask whether it's valid to worship someone other than YHVH, nor does it ask about any of the other points covered in the answer. The only part of this answer that actually answers the question is the very first sentence: "No Jesus does not reject worship." The rest is a non-answer.

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan It certainly makes sense to all those who he shares this same glory with.  (john 17:22)  We are the children of God.  Is not the Father also in you?  The Risen Son too?   Are you not One with them?  Are you not also the light of the world?  Do you not also reflect the Father's light to others?  Does that make sense?

Comment: @LeeWoofenden The question asks whether Jesus forbid worship before his resurrection.  I answered this in the first sentence.  Then I explained how this is not contradictory to the Shema... Jesus' most important command to us.  YHWH is 1.  Yes Jesus was worshiped!  We see that clearly. Instead of a "non-answer".....its more of a non-question that my rational answer dismantled. Shalom.